# Remove rows which have NA into specific columns and conditions

Tags: r

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), stock = c("stock2", NA, NA, NA), bill = c("stock3", "bill2", NA, NA)
```

I would like to remove the rows which have in both columns(stock, bill) missing values

Example output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), stock = c("stock2", NA), bill = c("stock3", "bill2")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to create a logical vector in `base R`

```
df1[rowSums(is.na(df1[-1])) < ncol(df1)-1,]
#   id  stock   bill
#1  1 stock2 stock3
#2  2   <NA>  bill2
```

---

Or using `filter_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   filter_at(-1,  any_vars(!is.na(.)))
#  id  stock   bill
#1  1 stock2 stock3
#2  2   <NA>  bill2
```

We can also specify the column names within `vars`

```
df1 %>%
    filter_at(vars(stock, bill), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

NOTE: This would also work when there are many columns to compare.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways using base R or `dplyr`

```
# the data frame with your values
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3,4), 
  stock = c("stock2", NA, NA, NA), 
  bill = c("stock3", "bill2", NA, NA)
)

# base R way
df[!(is.na(df$stock) & is.na(df$bill)), ]

# dplyr way
library(dplyr)

filter(df, !(is.na(stock) & is.na(bill)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can check for `NA` values in the dataframe and use `apply` to select rows which have at least one non-NA value.

```
df[apply(!is.na(df[-1]), 1, any), ]

#  id  stock   bill
#1  1 stock2 stock3
#2  2   <NA>  bill2
```

We can also use `Reduce` and `lapply` with same effect

```
df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[-1], function(x) !is.na(x))), ]
#OR
#df[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[-1], complete.cases)), ]
```